# Multiple LIKE statements in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a table containing information about retail stores. I have a list of retail chain names (WalMart, Target, Eatons, etc...) When the user selects one I basically run a query to find anything having to do with that chain.

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name LIKE '%$chain%' ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

For example, if the user selects 'WalMart', the query would return anything with the word 'WalMart' in it's name (WalMart Scarborough, WalMart Supercenter Toronto, WalMart Distribution Center etc...).

But now I would like to give the user the ability to search through this list via a search text box. The way I usually do searches is like so:

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name LIKE '%$user_input%' ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

But in this case the query will return ALL stores containing the `user_input`, not just WalMarts. If I type in Toronto I would like to see WalMart Supercenter Toronto, but will of course get Target Toronto etc....

How can I make it so that I'm looking for anything containing the `user_input` but also only within the WalMart subset. I would like to do this in a single query if possible. Can I use two `LIKE` statements like this?

Sorry, haven't tried anything yet as I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name LIKE '%$user_input%' 
AND store_name LIKE '%Walmart%'
ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

Comment: Of course, what was I thinking?? I ran that through my head before and it didn't seem right for some reason. I'm completely off the ball today, back at work after Christmas vacation... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just add two LIKE clauses:

```
SELECT * FROM stores 
WHERE store_name LIKE '%$chain%' 
AND store_name LIKE '%$user_input%'
ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be limited to a single store chain you go like that:

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name LIKE '%Walmart%' AND store_name LIKE '%$user_input%'      ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work i think:

```
   SELECT * FROM stores WHERE store_name LIKE '%$chain%' AND store_name LIKE '%$user_input%'  ORDER BY store_name ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, just use two LIKE. I would use also LOWER (applying lower case on the user_input as well) to make the query case independent.

```
SELECT * FROM stores WHERE LOWER(store_name) LIKE '%$user_input%' 
AND LOWER(store_name) LIKE '%walmart%'
ORDER BY store_name ASC
```