# SQL command error Incorrect Syntax near 'and'

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am a newbie student of VB.net and struggling through a form I cannot figure out how to solve. The form is a search form which can search the assets table based on four inputs. User can choose which inputs to give. The interface of the form looks like the picture I've attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyMZQ.png). The problem is that its giving me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and' error when I check any checkbox.

Any other approach to achieve the desired results is also highly encouraged.

I am using the following code

```
    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    sCommand = New SqlCommand("", con)
    Dim script As String
    script = "Select * from tblassets where [asset_costprice] like %"
    If checkassetsupplier.Checked = False AndAlso checkassetstatus.Checked = False AndAlso CheckassetID.Checked = False AndAlso checkassetsupplier.Checked = False Then
        sCommand.CommandText = "Select * from tblassets"
    End If
    If checkassetsupplier.Checked = True Then
        script = script & " and [Asset_supplier] = @p1"
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cbsearchsupplier.Text)
    End If
    If checkassetstatus.Checked = True Then
        script = script & " and asset_status = @p2"
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", cbsearchstatus.SelectedIndex)
    End If
    If CheckassetID.Checked = True Then
        script = script & " and asset_id = @p3"
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", tbsearchassetid.Text)
    End If
    If checkassetname.Checked = True Then
        script = script & " and asset_name = @p4"
        sCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", tbsearchassetname.Text)
    End If
    sCommand.CommandText = script
    sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(SMSSDataSet, SMSSDataSet.tblassets.TableName)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("No", GetType(Integer))
        .Columns.Add("Status", GetType(String))
        .Rows.Add("0", "Held")
        .Rows.Add("1", "Depreciated")
        .Rows.Add("2", "Partially Sold")
        .Rows.Add("3", "Sold")
    End With
    dgvsearch.AutoGenerateColumns = False
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Asset ID", .DataPropertyName = "asset_id", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader})
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Name", .DataPropertyName = "asset_name", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill})
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Price", .DataPropertyName = "unit_price", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill})
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Supplier", .DataPropertyName = "asset_supplier", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill})
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Status", .DataSource = dt, .DisplayMember = "Status", .ValueMember = "No", .DataPropertyName = "asset_status", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill})
    dgvsearch.Columns.Add(New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn() With {.HeaderText = "Quantity", .DataPropertyName = "quantity", .ReadOnly = True, .AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill})

    dgvsearch.DataSource = SMSSDataSet.tblassets


End Sub
```

Comment: `like %`...you are missing single quotes:`like '%`. And I assume that every other command needs another single quote before the `and`: `' and `

Comment: Just see the final output of your SQL query the is constructed in variable script. You should be e to figure it out figure it out yourself. One thing what I can see is immediately after statement "Select * from tblassets where [asset_costprice] like %", "and" is getting appended

Comment: Thank you guys for pointing it out. It dosen't give the error now but now it shows all records no matter what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark, but your script uses like but then doesn't say what it should be like, and doesn't have any ' ' to show what the like statement is.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Maybe change to this and see if it helps:

```
 script = "Select * from tblassets where [asset_costprice] like '%'"
```

I would also change all your ifs to have =' ' as well, and see what errors happen now.

Comment: Thank you @tyler for pointing this out. But when I use
    script = "Select * from tblassets where [asset_costprice] like '%'"
it shows every record no matter what parameters are supplied through other if statements.

Comment: That's not bad. At least its working. Give me a second to think about the problem and recommend another solution.

Comment: Since you are using a like statement, all subsequent statements might need to be like statements as well. For example look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20806361/multiple-like-statements-in-sql

Comment: So instead of, " and asset_status = @p2", you might need to change it to, " and asset_status like '@p2' "

Comment: Unfortunately I'm in a rush so I can't look at this more, but you could start with that.

Comment: Done that but it doesn't help.

Comment: Thank You so much for your time @tyler

Comment: Looks like the problem of all values was that the dataset loaded all rows automatically. When I used a new datatable for this, the problem was solved. My bad. I am marking this as an answer. Thank You Guys.